# VBA two buttons calling one Sub

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have two statistics tables in one Excel file. Their names are OO and XX.

I have separate subroutines to export and import each of OO and XX. That is:

```
1.Sub OO-export()
'do output data from OO sheet
End Sub

2.Sub XX-export()
'do output data from XX sheet
End Sub

3.Sub OO-import()
'Import Data to OO sheet
End Sub

4.Sub XX-import()
'Import Data to XX sheet
End Sub
```

Both import subroutines contain very similar code, and both export subroutines contain very similar code.

I would like to refactor the OO-/XX-specific subroutines to more generic import and export subroutines e.g. TT-import and TT-export.

The generic subroutines would conditionally process either OO or XX depending on which button the user clicks e.g. OO-button or XX-button.

How can I create common subroutines that can process the right table depending on which button was clicked? Give me some hints

Comment: Without any code I'm not sure anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 master subs with arguments. Then 4 small other subs can access the master sub providing the argument which will be used in that master sub.

```
Sub sub_A1()
  Call A("A1")
End Sub

Sub sub_A2()
  Call A("A2")
End Sub

Sub sub_B1()
  Call B("B1")
End Sub

Sub sub_B2()
  Call B("B2")
End Sub

Sub A(argument As String)
  MsgBox "Sub A was called by clicking button " & argument
End Sub

Sub B(argument As String)
  MsgBox "Sub B was called by clicking button " & argument
End Sub
```

Here `A` and `B` are master subs, which are referenced by smaller subs. Only the smaller subs are linked to buttons. When you click buttons `A1` and `A2`, initially `sub_A1` and`sub_A2` are accessed, but they only send the argument to the main function `A`, where you can do whatever you want with that argument. In this case, sub `A` simply prints what it receives.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the argument with String is just an example. It can be any type, even a reference to Worksheet.